# Issue with menu and user token

Tags: users, tokens, navigation, 7

I'm having problems with some links that have a user token in it.

For ex. I have a link like this: `user/[current-user:uid]/edit`. 
But when I check this in the browser as a user I just see `Edit` instead of my Menu link title. I also get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: localized_options in menu_navigation_links() (line 1861 of /includes/menu.inc).

When I check this is as an admin I see the correct title and no error.

When I change permissions of `Administer users` and set to all users I can see it as a user to, but that's not the way to do it because now a user can cancel his account and change the role ... .

In my search quest I've found [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1918930) but the solution #2 didn't help much.

I'm using the [Menu Token Module](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) and these are my configurations (user is set as you can see):

[image]

These are my link configurations:
[image]

As you can see I tried the solution from the issue on drupal.org.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with the following steps:

1. Uncheck "Use token", change the "path" to normal path without using menu token.
2. Save the change.
3. Edit the menu, check "Use token", change the "path" to [current-user:edit-url]
4. Save.